# PyQT Save text line to file

Tags: save, line, pyqt5

I am trying to save text entered by a user but something is not working.  it writes the file but there is nothing in it.  if you can help that would be awesome.  If you can show me a way to use the windows save dialogue box, that would be even better.

here's what I am using.

```
def save_to_file(self):
    test1 = self.NetAddline.text
    test2 = self.NumHosline.text

    if test1 == "" or test2 == "":
        QMessageBox.information(self, "Please enter network address and number of host before selecting save", QMessageBox.Ok)
        return
    else:
        with open("SubNetSave.txt", "w") as CurrentFile:
            CurrentFile.write(str(test1))
            CurrentFile.write("\n")
            CurrentFile.write(str(test2))
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Your file has been saved under file name SubNetSave.txt", QMessageBox.Ok)
```

Answer (score 0):

with your code test1 and test 2 always are something like this:

```
<built-in method text of QLineEdit object at 0x7f0b97abfca8>
```

get the return value of this method by:

```
test1 = self.NetAddline.text()
test2 = self.NumHosline.text()
```